# Creating and Storing an array / Dynamic array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach, checkbox

I have issues with creating an array and storing the info, I have a table with data that could be infinite in its number, a user will then select some options which will determine which of these values they can select (which again is an infinite number), these choices are then presented into a checkbox where i use this code

```
<?php foreach ( $results['detailsline'] as $detailsline )
 {
$invoice_details = $detailsline->details_line;

echo $invoice_details;
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="invoice_details" value="'.$invoice_details.'"/>';  
  }             
 ?>
```

So this should search through the options they previous choose, and sorts them into an array and then into checkboxs, but when i store the information is just saves the last box checked, I cant change the value of each input EG

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="invoice_details[value1]" 
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="invoice_details[value2]"
```

Because I don't know how many values/checkboxes there will be.
I have also tried this

```
    <?php foreach ( $results['detailsline'] as $detailsline )
 {
$invoice_details[] = $detailsline->details_line;

echo $invoice_details[];
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="invoice_details[]" value="'.$invoice_details.'"/>';  
  }             
 ?>
```

Changing the

```
    $invoice_details
```

to

```
$invoice_details[]
```

but this will just store a value "Array" in my database and not the actual values.

Please can anyone help me?

Ian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey I think You should Try this:

```
<?php 
$i=0;
foreach ( $results['detailsline'] as $detailsline )
{
$invoice_details = $detailsline->details_line;
echo $invoice_details;
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="invoice_details[$i]" value="'.$invoice_details.'"/>';  
$i++;
}             
?>
```

Comment: It seems my problem is storing the value into the database, I think i need to convert it to a string but am at a loss. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Your use of $i was great for getting the echo stuff to work, thanks greatly for that. Now just storing the array as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php foreach ( $results['detailsline'] as $detailsline )
 {
$invoice_details = $detailsline->details_line;

echo $invoice_details;
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="invoice_details[]" value="'.$invoice_details.'"/>';  
  }             
 ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I need to convert the array to a string before submitting, as i have found that the first set of code i was using is working and storing the correct value in each array iteration but i am soooo confussed when converting the selected boxes to a string

Answer (score 0):

Use `<input type="checkbox" name="invoice_details[]">`

In your code you can use `serialize($invoice_details)` for saving into DB and when using - `unserialize($field_from_db)`.

First function returns string, so you can save it as string field, second function get the string and returns the whole array, so you can work with it.

Answer (score 0):

> but this will just store a value "Array" in my database and not the actual values.

think you tried to store Array as string so got that value
So may be needed to use implode/serialize/json_encode (Array) to store data?

Answer (score 0):

Literally saying code `$invoice_details[] = $detailsline->details_line;` means take property **details_line** of an object **$detailsline** and insert its value as new element in array **$invoice_details**. Are you sure it is what you want?) Also I suppose that **$detailsline** is an array, but not the object (you trying to operate it as an object)